# Events added in android calendar disappear automatically after a few seconds?

Tags: android, google-calendar-api, android-calendar

I wanted to create an event in google calendar. The following code created an event successfully and also I can get the created event Id. When I open the google calendar, I can see the event only for some seconds. After some time, It disappears. What is wrong?

```
 try {

        long startMillis = 0L;
        long endMillis = 0L;

        try {
            SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm a", Locale.getDefault());
            String startDate = estimationListItems.geteSStart();
            startMillis = sdf.parse(startDate).getTime();

            String endDate = estimationListItems.geteSEnd();
            endMillis = sdf.parse(endDate).getTime();

            AppLogger.e("startMillis : " + startMillis);
            AppLogger.e("endMillis : " + endMillis);

        } catch (ParseException pe) {
            pe.printStackTrace();
            AppLogger.e("ParseException : " + pe.getMessage());
        }

        ContentResolver cr = context.getContentResolver();
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(CalendarContract.Events.DTSTART, startMillis);
        values.put(CalendarContract.Events.DTEND, endMillis);
        values.put(CalendarContract.Events.TITLE, estimationListItems.getDisplayEId());
        values.put(CalendarContract.Events.DESCRIPTION, estimationListItems.getEuAddress());
        values.put(CalendarContract.Events.CALENDAR_ID, calendarId);
        values.put(CalendarContract.Events.ALL_DAY, false);
        values.put(CalendarContract.Events.EVENT_TIMEZONE, TimeZone.getDefault().getID());

        Uri uri = cr.insert(CalendarContract.Events.CONTENT_URI, values);

        long eventID = Long.parseLong(uri.getLastPathSegment());
        AppLogger.e(" Event  added: " + eventID);

        syncCalendar(context, String.valueOf(calendarId));
    } catch (SecurityException se) {
        se.printStackTrace();
    }
```

After Adding the event, I sync the calendar.

```
    private void syncCalendar(Context context, String calendarId) {

    Uri CALENDAR_URI = Uri.parse("content://com.android.calendar/calendars");
    ContentResolver cr = context.getContentResolver();
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(CalendarContract.Calendars.SYNC_EVENTS, 1);
    values.put(CalendarContract.Calendars.VISIBLE, 1);

    AppLogger.e("syncCalendar Success");

    cr.update(
            ContentUris.withAppendedId(CALENDAR_URI, Long.parseLong(calendarId)), values, null, null);
}
```

Comment: Did you figured out what was wrong?

Comment: @JanMaděra Yes. I made it. Please let me know if you wanna know.

Comment: I already solve this by using Goolge Calendar API instead of Calendar Provider. But thanks for answer.

Comment: @Rethinavel what is the solution please?

Comment: @LazarosPapadopoulos The calendar ID you are getting is wrong. That is the problem. Get the correct ID and try to update. `values.put(CalendarContract.Events.CALENDAR_ID, calendarId);`